# java cacheing - choice between using a Map and using a Graph

Tags: java, spring, caching, google-guava-cache

in my java Spring application, I need to build an in-process / in-memory cache of some configuration metadata, which is structured like this:

```
Graph<String customerName, Map<String, JSONObject> customerMetadata>:

  "My Customer" "CustomerInfo":
                    {IngestionConfig:  {"data": "schema":{"fields"[]}}}
                "Asset"
                    {IngestionConfig:  {"data": "schema":{"fields"[]}}}
                "Invoice"
                    {IngestionConfig:  {"data": "schema":{"fields"[]}}}
```

Question:

What technique is better suited for this purpose: a Map, a ValueGraph from Google Guava, EhCache, or some other?

Comment: At what granularity do you want to load when a cache miss occurs?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends. Do you want your cache to be expiring after certain time by itself? will you ever need your map to be distributed? Is it read-only or are you planning to update it run-time? If its not read only, is your environment single threaded or multi? 
If you don't need any of those bells and whistles and if its READ-only, I would rather go with Map (or whatever packed with Java). 
(This is just  an opinion -- I am a minimalistic person.)